# Leaving Windows Console windows open after process termination

Tags: windows, debugging, console

### Is there an OS or user-account level modification for windows 7 that I can use to leave the console window of terminated processes open?

**Background:** I like to use console programs for simple tests.  These things tend to need debugging and analysis, and the easiest way to do that is to use `printf` or equivalent - that's available in pretty much any language.  Unfortunately, when a console program terminates, the window containing the text buffer exits - and I lose that simple feedback.

When you start a program from within Visual Studio (without debugging), however, Visual studio manages to start the program and leaves the console window open after the process terminates - that behavior is handy!  Unfortunately, I can't start all processes from visual studio.

So, is there a way to start *all* programs or at least some programs such that their console window remains open until I close it rather than until the process exits?  I'm dreaming of some really simple tool (or registry setting) to make windows a bit more suitable for simple development tasks.

**Two specific cases:** starting freshly compiled programs from a batch file (a simple unit test, essentially), and starting programs via explorer or some other external app (i.e. without being able to pass parameters).

**Further Requirements:** Ideally, any solution should work regardless of the console program started; in particular it should not depend on the language or runtime of the program, and it should not require changes to programs started or as few as possible.

**In particular:** I can always redirect output to a logfile, so I'm looking for something that's simpler than that; i.e. does not require maintaining filenames and managing files.  Something you could use without hassle several times a minute and with multiple parallel processes.  Pausing at the end of execution is a workaround that requires a code change and will break other callers of that process (since the process never terminates), so it's hardly better than logfiles and not always usable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of running your program, why not execute it via a shell command like cmd.exe /K this should keep the console that your program ran around. This should work in all cases regardless of how the program is built.

Comment: Sounds like a decent idea!  It's not entirely ideal - this won't work from explorer or another app, for instance, but if I have detailed control of the starting parameters, this'll do!

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible for you to just add `Console.Read();` at the end of the program? It will keep Console window up, and will close when you press any key.

Comment: This isn't practical - doing so keeps the process alive, which affects things like file locking.  Many apps aren't C#.  Some are plugin-like - i.e. I don't get to control Main().  Finally, adding Console.Read() breaks the app if it's used in a pipe-line or whatever.  So, where possible, I do this, but it's not usually possible.

Answer (score 0):

For using explorer you can add a command "Run & Wait" to the explorers context menu. It doesn't require programming.
This page explains how to do this in general:

http://www.petri.co.il/add_command_prompt_here_shortcut_to_windows_explorer.htm

If you run your tests from a batch file, why don't you just add a `pause` statement at the end? This of course wont work if you start the tests from explorer.